# get count magento collection per day and weekly

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection

I have table in magento database

```
 CREATE TABLE `topup` (
  `topup_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `msisdn` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ipn_response` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`topup_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want magento collection `SELECT count(*) FROM topup AS main_table`

I want total count base on `created_at` in 1 day

and

total count in week

week start from Monday.

Comment: you want a magento collection or a simple select that groups everything by date?

Comment: just want count create_at whole day e.g.   WHERE (created_at >= '2016-12-05 00:00:00' AND created_at <= '2016-12-05 18:08:39') and in total count in week e.g. form monday to now week of day

Comment: @ArshadMuhammad you can get count `WHERE  created_at LIKE  '2016-12-05 %'` for current day

Comment: @QaisarSatti got and for whole week how can i do week start from like monday

Comment: @ArshadMuhammad added the answer check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rough idea hope work for you

For current day

```
WHERE created_at LIKE '2016-12-05 %'
```

For weekly

```
$lastmonday=date('Y-m-d', ("last Monday")).' 00:00:00';
$currentday=date('Y-m-d').' 23:59:00';

 WHERE (created_at >= $lastmonday AND created_at <= $currentday)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this for grouping my day.

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
FROM topup 
WHERE 
    DATE(created_at) = '2016-12-05'
```

Or for today you can replace '2016-12-05' with `DATE(NOW())`

so you get:

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
FROM topup 
WHERE 
    DATE(created_at) = DATE(NOW())
```

and for records this week

```
SELECT 
    count(*) 
FROM topup 
WHERE 
    WEEKOFYEAR(created_at)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
```

Comment: e.g. week start from today monday how can i do

Comment: I don't understand. Can't you just calculate in php when the last monday was and run a query with `Where date(created_at) >= 'date you calculate in php' `